# How to assign of first objects into other object in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

There are two objects, we have to put first object into the second object.

**first Object**

```
var inputData1 = {
    'first':{'name':'aa', 'age':11},
    'second': {'name':'aa', 'age':11}
};
```

**Second Object**

```
var inputData2 = {
    'group': {
         _id: null
    }
}
```

**Output Object**

```
var output = {
    'group':{
       _id: null,
       first: {name:'aa', 'age':11},
       second: {name: 'bb', age: 21} 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+How+to+Merge+objects) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function. It copies the `enumerable` properties of the objects into the destination object.

```js
var inputData1 = {
    'first':{'name':'aa', 'age':11},
    'second': {'name':'aa', 'age':11}
};

var inputData2 = {
    'group': {
        _id: null
    }
};

Object.assign(inputData2.group, inputData1);

console.log(inputData2);
```